# Mongoose query on json array

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am new to node.js and using mongoose along with node.js.

Schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: String,
password: String,
phone_no : String,
email: String,
name:String,
dob: {type: Date, "default": Date.now},
city:String,
locality:{lattitude:Number,longitude:Number},
sports: [String]
});
```

sample entry:

```
"userId": 10,
    "username": "shu",
    "name": "shubham goyal",
    "password": "ahu",
    "phone_no": "919357701457",
    "email": "shubham2892@gmail.com",
    "city": "delhi",
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5331dbc243bb59f80a7ed60b"
    },
    "sports": [
        "cricket,football"
    ],
    "dob": {
        "$date": "2014-03-25T19:40:50.886Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

The query i am trying to make:

```
models.user.find({'sports' : sports_selected},function(err,users) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("Cannot fetch sports with requested username" + req.user.username);
            console.log(err);
        }if(!users){
            console.log("cannot find specified username" + req.user.username);
        }else{
            console.log(users.username);
            //sport = player.sports;
            //sport = ['cricket','football','basketball'];

            }
        });
```

I am getting undefined in users.username.I want to return all users who have selected a particular sports say 'cricket'.I googled it a lot but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your sample entry is incorrectly formatted. Sports entry shouldn't be like this:

```
"sports": [
        "cricket,football"
]
```

You should keep the sports data like this instead:

```
"sports": [
        "cricket","football"
]
```

If you provide cricket and football in the same string, mongo cannot differentiate these two as different sports.

Also users should be an array, so you need to loop through the array. Say you have one user with sport selected as cricket, then you can print **users[0].username**